# VueJS + element.eleme.io How to set default option value for el-select

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have an el-select of which uses v-for to populate data from an array; i want to set the default value on load a value within the array, but still have the option of selecting another value if i want...

**CODE**

```
<el-select class="select-large" @change="getRate(recipient_type_id)" v-model="recipient_type_id"
      placeholder="Select">
     <el-option
        v-for="(item) in recipientDetails"
           :key="item.id"
           :label="item.display_name"
           :value="item.type_details">
     </el-option>
 </el-select>
```

the array is *recipientDetails* and i have a default recipient whom should be loaded first instead of the placeholder...

thanks in advance

Comment: `v-attr="{ item.preselected ? 'selected' : '' }"`

Comment: Or `v-attr="{ 'selected': item.preselected }"` if `item.preselected`is your `boolean`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using v-model on select, you can't use the `selected` attribute on an option.

Since you've bound the select to `recipient_type_id`, Once your data loads, I'll advice you to run through the items in `recipientDetails`, find the item with a `type_details` property that should be the default and assign that value to `recipient_type_id` like so

```
this.recipientDetails.forEach(detail => {
    if(detail.tpye_details == default_value){
        this.recipient_type_id = detail.type_details
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can selected option via set a value for `:selected` attrs of `

```
     <el-option
        v-for="(item) in recipientDetails"
           :selected="other_detail"
           :key="item.id"
           :label="item.display_name"
           :value="item.type_details">
     </el-option>
```

if `other_detail` equals `:value` value, so the option selected.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found is to have the default value assigned to *recipient_type_id* is the ***data()*** then it will filter automatically.